# Cake php baking function in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, cakephp-3.0

I am an experienced developer in cake and a beginner in Laravel.
Does Laravel5 have a function similar to baking in CakePHP?

Comment: what baking in cakephp

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also a CakePHP dev learning Laravel. In Cakephp you build the database then reproduce the db schema in terms of baking the CRUD, in the Controller/Model and Views. In Laravel you build the db in the code (migrations) then you can build the Controller and Model in artisan (comman line tool) but the Controller and Model is basically just the bare skeleton and not usable as it is.No views are created. In Cakephp I configure the baking templates to build the views I would like them. This speeds up development a lot. It is the one thing that makes Cakephp preferable to Laravel.

Comment: I agree, same with me I am a Cakephp Dev learning Laravel as most jobs are for Laravel dev's here in the UK. If Laravel replicate the Cakebake function, it will make Laravel so much nicer. I do like the lack of html helper in the views thou and blade minimize the php. I have written a class in cakephp that replicate the Laravel migrate functionality in cakephp.

Comment: yes similar command is - artisan make: commands check more on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan